# Recipe commences before first target. Stop. While running a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, executable

I've been working on this makefile for several hours and I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to make six different exectuables (Q1-Q6)but I keep getting the error that reads above. heres my code

```
BUILD_FLAGS= -W -Wall -pedantic
CC=g++
RM=rm
EXES=*.exe
OBJECTS=*.o
g++ -c Question1.cpp
g++ -c Question2.cpp
g++ -c Question3.cpp
g++ -c Question4.cpp
g++ -c Question5.cpp
g++ -c Question6.cpp
g++ -o Question1.exe Question1.o
g++ -o Question2.exe Question2.o
g++ -o Question3.exe Question3.o
g++ -o Question4.exe Question4.o
g++ -o Question5.exe Question5.o
g++ -o Question6.exe Question6.o

clean:
     $(RM)$(EXES)$(OBJECTS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
BUILD_FLAGS=-W -Wall -pedantic
CC=g++
RM=rm
EXES=*.exe
OBJECTS=*.o

all: Question1.exe Question2.exe Question3.exe Question4.exe Question5.exe Question6.exe

%.exe: %.cpp
    g++ ${BUILD_FLAGS} -o $@ $<

clean:
   $(RM) $(EXES)
```